# 400 Bad Request randomly when should be 404

Tags: bash, apache, wget, http-status-code-400

The dev team came to me and the Senior Sys Admin and stated that a 400 error is popping up when it needs to be a 404.

I ran an infinite loop to see the output with:

```
while :; do wget http://<URL here>/-`date +%s`; sleep 1; done
```

It just appends an incremented Unix timestamp since I know it should be a 404. The output shows 404 every 10-15 iterations, then shows a single 400, then repeats the cycle.

We have tried to edit the ErrorDocument directive to point to a custom 404 error document to no avail.

What could be causing this 400 error to pop up every few requests?

Comment: Examine server side logs.

Comment: This might be a better question for [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks. Posted question there as well.